# Spring cloud Sleuth - traceId does not propagate for RestTemplate

Tags: spring, logging, httpclient, resttemplate, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am trying to use Spring cloud Sleuth, however i am facing an issue with having proper log information. My application does not propagate traceId and spanId for RestTemplate.

I am using the latest version of Sleuth.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the logs:

```
2021-07-19 10:46:22.834 DEBUG [My app,340b0c68ce92b6be,340b0c68ce92b6be] 28840 --- [       Thread-3] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-0 << Date: Mon, 19 Jul 2021 08:46:15 GMT
2021-07-19 10:46:22.834 DEBUG [My app,340b0c68ce92b6be,340b0c68ce92b6be] 28840 --- [       Thread-3] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2021-07-19 10:46:22.834 DEBUG [My app,,] 28840 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2021-07-19 10:46:22.834 DEBUG [My app,,] 28840 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [com.app.myapp.DeviceService]
2021-07-19 10:46:22.834 DEBUG [My app,,] 28840 --- [       Thread-3] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://ttsce.dot.eu:443] can be kept alive indefinitely
2021-07-19 10:46:22.844 DEBUG [My app,,] 28840 --- [       Thread-3] .w.m.TracingClientHttpRequestInterceptor : Wrapping an outbound http call with span [NoopSpan(4bda0829902d27f6/4bda0829902d27f6)]
2021-07-19 10:46:22.844 DEBUG [My app,4bda0829902d27f6,4bda0829902d27f6] 28840 --- [       Thread-3] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: default
```

This is how i am craeting my RestTemplate bean (i was testing with both those setups of the bean).

```
@Primary
@Bean("newRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@Bean("customRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(300000))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(300000)).build();
}
```